# iOS scroll view starts at non zero offset

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a ScrollView that is supposed to be scrolled only downwards. The content View's size matches scrollview identically. I use this code to prevent from scrolling up:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

#define CONTENT_OFFSET 0

NSLog(@"%f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);

//prevent from scrolling up
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > CONTENT_OFFSET) {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CONTENT_OFFSET);
}
```

}

It used to work perfectly. But now for some reason scroll view starts at -44 points and is of course scrollable up to 0. In between -44 and 0 it doesn't bounce if drag ended. I'm pretty sure I have not changed anything in layout but I might have unintentionally. I think scroll view now has bigger content view for some reason. Where do I look for the origin of this problem?

Comment: Double check the layout. In iOS8 strange things tend to happen in Interface Builder. Also, show the code where you initialize this scroll view and/or populate it with some content (images or whatever you are placing inside).

Comment: There is no code, all is done in IB. I only set delegate in `-viewDidLoad` method. The most annoying thing is that it used to work like this morning and I have not touched this controller at all.

Comment: 44 is the height of a nav bar. Is your view controller now embedded within a nav controller?

Comment: It is embedded, but it already was when it did work fine, nothing has changed in that regard. Still can't find what's causing this, I'm afraid I have to roll back to previous state and throw away a day of work.